# Uncertain about sudden changes in water pressure

Tags: plumbing

**Dilemma**

I have two showers; one upstairs and one downstairs. Tonight, both showers had low water pressure - but the sink water pressure seemed normal. I have checked around the house and no water appears to be leaking and the lawn sprinklers are also not on. I am not sure what to check next.

**Question**

What could be causing this?